# HTML5 Canvas antialias

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, antialiasing

The [Example](http://jsbin.com/yuhozet/edit?js,console,output).

Hello every body.
I have a Canvas with red background.
On it I have rows of boxes, which go exactly after each other.
Each box begins exactly where previous box ends, and they all have same skew.
So there should not be any gap between edges, but as you can see in the example there are gaps.

Does anybody knows why is this happening, and how to get rid of it.

```js
console.clear();
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var world = {
  centerY: canvas.height / 2,
  centerX: canvas.width / 2
}
var rowCount = 14;
var box = {
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  skew: 10
}

function drawBox(x, y, id) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + box.width, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + box.width + box.skew, y - 20);
  ctx.lineTo(x + box.skew, y - box.height);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = id % 2 == 0 ? 'lightgray' : 'darkgray';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();

}

for (var i = 0; i < 112; i++) {
  var k = Math.floor(i / rowCount) * rowCount;
  console.log(k);
  drawBox(i * box.width - (k * box.width), Math.floor(i / rowCount) * box.height, i)
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: red;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas">

  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add one pixel to the right side of each box and the hole goes away

Comment: @Blindman67 that doesn't work when

`ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

applyed.

Comment: Have you updated jsBin?

Comment: Yes I have updated jsBin.

Comment: Don't use the clear. You can never get perfect seams on the canvas so you have to work with it. I can not see why you need to clear when you do a fill in that colour.

Comment: I am drawing blocks of images along a Path, but because of curved line, blocks are interfering.
I need to clear area before image draw.

Without clearRect. -> https://postimg.org/image/6wwf25ixd/
With clearRect       -> https://postimg.org/image/utbwpuiub/

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want.... But Then maybe you can save co-ordinates in an array for drawing image. Then after the pattern is painted, you can while painting image use clearRect

Comment: I do so, but after clear, between drawings there are gaps, just like in example.

Answer (score 0):

In function drawBox Updated:

```
  ctx.lineTo(x+box.width, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x+box.width + box.skew, y - 20);
```

To

```
ctx.lineTo(x+box.width+1, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+box.width + box.skew +1, y - 20);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add
`ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`
after
`ctx.clip()`